# HTML5 Canvas drag and drop multiple texts

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I have an application where the user has the ability to add captions, my only problem is that I am having problem with dragging and dropping multiple texts. With the usual mousedown, mousemove, mouseup events I am only able to drag and drop one text, I want to have the ability to drag and drop multiple texts however I don't have a clear approach to this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: My code is messed up when I am trying to drag both of the texts, but I will post it anyways.

thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id = 'canvas'></canvas>
<textarea id = 'topCaption'></textarea>
<textarea id = 'bottomCaption'></textarea>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>


window.addEventListener('load',initCanvas,false);

function initCanvas(e)
{
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.width = 500;
mouse = {x:0,y:0};
dragging = false;
topCap = document.getElementById('topCaption');
bottomCap = document.getElementById('bottomCaption');
topX = 100; //top x position
topY = 100; //top y position
botX = 300; //bottom x position
botY = 300; //bottom y position
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',MouseMove,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',MouseUp,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',MouseDown,false);
window.addEventListener('keyup',KeyUp,false);
return setInterval(keyup,10)
}
function clear()
{
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

function text(Caption,x,y)
{
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.font = '45px Impact';        //'bold 45px impact';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.lineCap = 'round';
context.lineJoin = 'round';
context.fill();
context.stroke();
context.fillText(Caption,x,y);
};




function MouseMove(event){
mouse.x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
mouse.y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
if(dragging)
{
context.lineTo(mouse.x,mouse.y);
}
}



function MouseDown(event)
{
dragging = true;
setInterval(function(){
topX = mouse.x;
topY = mouse.y;
botX = mouse.x;
botY = mouse.y;
},10)
}

function MouseUp(event)
{
if(dragging)
{
dragging = false;
}
}

function KeyUp(event)
{
clear();
text(topCap.value.toUpperCase(),topX,topY);
text(bottomCap.value.toUpperCase(),botX,botY);

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us to look at and the code of what you've tried. How are the texts selected? How are you enabling multiple texts to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you understand basic dragging by listening to mouse events, so here's the outline of a method to drag multiple items:

Listen for mousedown, mouseup and mousemove.

If you get a mousedown+mouseup inside a text boundingbox with <10px of mousemove in-between, "select" this text (maybe add its reference to a "selected" array)

If you get a mousedown followed by 10+ pixels of mousemove, its a "drag" (move all text in the "selected" array).